# How to validate x509 certificate against CRL byte array in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, openssl, ldap

I am using **OpenSSL** to get the byte array of CRL (**certificateRevocationList**) with a specific dn from my local ldap server.

The CRL data is an ASN1 byte array as follows:

```
<308202bb 308201a3 02010130 0d06092a 864886f7 ... d179fa>
```

My intention is to validate a X509 certificate against the CRL.
I think I can use X509_CRL_get0_by_cert() to verify a certificate
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/X509_CRL_get0_by_cert.html

**But first I need to create a X509_CRL structure from the byte array.**
After that I need to verify my certificate against the X509_CRL.

Please help me to find a way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create BIO first. After that use d2i_X509_CRL_bio to create crl.
Appoximatelly like this:

```
BIO* memoryBIO = BIO_new_mem_buf(buffer, bufferSize);
X509_CRL* crl = d2i_X509_CRL_bio(memoryBIO, NULL);
```